# Getting value from database and passing to another page

Tags: asp.net

Ok I don't know if my question makes sense but I'll try to describe this as best as I can.

I am doing a school project and I have a database which stores "Projects", fields include ProjectID, Name, Publications, Status and so on.

I also have another table called Publications, which stores ID, PublicationType, ProjectID, Description and so on.

On the project page, I have the option to add a new project, and it also shows a grid view of the Current projects, and if you click on their name, it takes you to a page where you can add Publications for that project. I pass the Value of ProjectID through a HyperLinkField with the value Publications.aspx?ProjectID={0}

The ProjectID appears in the URL when I'm redirected to the Publications page, however, when I try to insert My publications, Name, Type and ProjectID the ProjectID field is left empty in my database.

I'm doing this in design view but here are my Insert and Select statements for the Publications page.

```
SELECT ProjectID, PubType, PubDescription, PubDetail, PubLink FROM Publications WHERE (ProjectID = ProjectID)

INSERT INTO Publications(ProjectID, PubType, PubDescription, PubDetail, PubLink) VALUES (ProjectID, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I'm 100% sure this is a logical error, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I would appreciate some help, preferably through the design interface, but I don't mind doing some of the coding if it's required.

Thanks !~

Comment: Is this using a SqlDataSource?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SelectCommand="ProjectID, PubType, PubDescription, PubDetail, PubLink FROM Publications WHERE ProjectID = @prodID"
```

And the add a select parameter

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="prodID" QueryStringField="ProjectID " />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Ok I will try those options guys. Thanks a lot. 

Just another question. How would I dream about doing a Dropdown menu of all the Project Names, when the user selects a name, they are able to add publications for that project. No idea how to link the Name and ID of the project